# Difference between (int*) calloc and just calloc?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, allocation

What is the difference between:

```
int *array;
array = (int*) calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

and

```
int *array;
array = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

I don't get it.
Both samples work.
At the university the professor explained why you need the (int*) before the calloc, but I didn't get it.

In the course was a code sample like this:

```
struct data{
   int number;
   char *name;
};
typedef struct data student;

int main(){
    student **list;
    list = (student*) calloc(10, sizeof(student*));

    //Create structures dynamic in list
    ....

    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can explain it to me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that, first causes constraint violation while second is not. Return type of `calloc` is `void *`, therefore no need to cast it.

Also read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2455888)